# Ember JS - Unable to loop through an array returned from the model even though it is an array?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two Ember JS models (in an Ember CLI application):

- list
- link

Each list can have multiple links and as a result, I've declared my list model as:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title       : DS.attr('string'),
    slug        : DS.attr('string'),
    visibility  : DS.attr('string'),
    owner       : DS.attr('string'),
    links       : DS.hasMany('link')
});
```

This is what the link model looks like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title   : DS.attr('string'),
    shortUrl: DS.attr('string'),
    views   : DS.attr('number'),
    owner   : DS.attr('string')
});
```

Within the list.js route, I make a call to fetch the list and its links like this:

```
model: function(params) {
        // Get list properties and links
        var list = this.store.find('list', params.listName);

        return list;
    },
```

The REST adapter correctly makes the call and my server returns the following response:

```
{
  "lists": [
    {
      "title": "Design",
      "slug": "design",
      "visibility": "private",
      "owner": "5540b2fb9611f67a07f7f6c1",
      "id": "5565ae05ca217589bc2a1bdf",
      "links": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Dribbble - Show and tell for designers",
      "shortUrl": "http://sl.fi/a1CRgc",
      "views": 144,
      "owner": "5540b2fb9611f67a07f7f6c1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Dribbble - Show and tell for designers",
      "shortUrl": "http://sl.fi/a1CRgc",
      "views": 144,
      "owner": "5540b2fb9611f67a07f7f6c1"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Dribbble - Show and tell for designers",
      "shortUrl": "http://sl.fi/a1CRgc",
      "views": 144,
      "owner": "5540b2fb9611f67a07f7f6c1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I modeled my response based on the [Ember Data Model Maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/). I have a list template that should loop through the links in the model so I am doing this:

```
{{#each links in model}}
    <span>{{ links.title }}</span>
{{/each}}
```

I get the following error when I load my application and I just can't seem to figure out a solution:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed <web-app@model:list::ember388:5565ae05ca217589bc2a1bdf>
```

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

links is a child relation to lists, the links array becomes a property on lists...

therefore your each helper should be:

`{{#each link in model.links}}`

also, you will want to start using the new syntax soon too.. (depending on your ember version):

`{{#each model.links as |links|}}`

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Not sure why I couldn't find answers to this anywhere. Also, how would I access the list properties returned in the response JSON using Handlebars in a template? I would like to show the list title that you see in the JSON above. I tried looping through the list array too but it didn't show up on the page.

Comment: `{{#each model as |list|}}` will loop through your model array (if it _is_ an array) and you can access title with `list.title`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work! When I script my server to send back lists as an array, Ember throws an error saying it wants an object: `Error while processing route: list Assertion Failed: Expected an object as data`. When I pass an object, I can't loop through it.

Comment: ah ok... because of this: `this.store.find('list', params.listName)` ember is expecting a single object record from the server.. not an array.. that is why.  and you cant loop over an single object only an array.

Comment: That makes sense. If that's the case, how would I access list properties in the template using Handlebars? I tried something like `<p>{{ model.lists.owner }}</p>` and it didn't render anything.

Comment: just try `{{model.owner}}`

Comment: That worked! Awesome! I can't believe how simple solutions are overlooked. Thank you again.